# Spring Webflux how to save child entity with parent entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am working on a Spring webflux project, I am stuck at one place where I want to save my all child entity with parent entity, below is the scenario.

Tables :

```
create table student(
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name varchar(256),
    primary key(id)
);

create table address(
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    address1 varchar(256),
    city varchar(256),
    state varchar(256),
    student_id integer,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(student_id) references student(id) on delete cascade
);
```

As **Hibernate** support a feature where all child entity gets save when we save parent entity.

But I am not using Hibernate as it is blocking operation in webflux.

Classes :

```
@Table
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    //Getter & Setter
}
@Table
public class Address {

    @Id private Integer id;
    private String address1;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private Integer studentId;
    //Getter & Setter
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Student, Integer> {
}
```

Spring Webflux code:

```
@Test
public void givenOrder_shouldCreateOrder(){
    Student order = new Student();
    order.setName("Alpesh");
    Mono<Student> orderMono = studentService.save(order);
    Mono<Address> addressMono = orderMono.flatMap(student -> {
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setAddress1("This is address1");
        address.setCity("Pune");
        address.setState("MH");
        address.setStudentId(student.getId());
        return addressRepository.save(address);
    });
    StepVerifier.create(addressMono)
            .expectNextMatches(student -> student.getId()>0)
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

This code is working but is this a good practice or there are other way to do this ?

Can someone please help me to make this better ?

Thanks
Alpesh

Comment: impossible for us to know since you have not disclosed what database driver you are using. Hibernate is not blocking, its the JDBC driver that is blocking. What database driver are you using?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I am using R2DBC driver.